# Creating .lyr file to import symbology using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, symbology, layer-file

I am trying to create a .lyr file in order to import symbology to a .shp file. The ESRI link says to use ModelBuilder to do this, but I am having trouble understanding the directions bc I haven't used ModelBuilder in forever....

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/creating-a-layer-symbology-file.htm

I got as far as the attached photo, but am unsure of actually how to save the file. It mentions 'adding to display' but when I do nothing comes up.

[image]

Comment: If you are creating a layer file from scratch you don't need modelbuilder.  You need to open the dataset in ArcMap, set up the symbology, then right click on the layer and click 'save as layer file'.

Comment: I have set up the symbology. Right click on the layer in the Table of Contents?

Comment: Correct.  See my answer :).

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating a layer file from scratch you don't need modelbuilder. You need to open the dataset in ArcMap, set up the symbology, then right click on the layer and click 'save as layer file'.  Choose the location to save the .lyr file.  You can then use that .lyr file to apply symbology.  You can do this by importing symbology from the .lyr file or by changing the datasource of the .lyr file to the new dataset.

[image]